# React: mapping of scraped HTML content to objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm looking at an example of using Cheerio and I found one of someone scraping the HTML data of a page and then mapping the `li` elements to objects.

```
  async loadData() {
    const searchUrl = `https://www.amazon.de/s/?page=1&keywords=graphic+card`;
    const response = await fetch(searchUrl);  // fetch page 

    const htmlString = await response.text(); // get response text
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlString);       // parse HTML string

    return $("#s-results-list-atf > li")             // select result <li>s
      .map((_, li) => ({                      // map to an list of objects
        asin: $(li).data("asin"),                   
        title: "$(\"h2\", li).text()",             
        price: $("span.a-color-price", li).text(),
        rating: $("span.a-icon-alt", li).text(),
        imageUrl: $("img.s-access-image").attr("src")
      }));
  }
```

What exactly is going when those `li`'s are getting mapped?  Where are the objects saved to and how can they be referenced again?